# What's the fastest way to seed grapes (e.g., Concordes)?

Tags: seeds, grapes

I've got a bunch of grapes, with seeds. I need to seed them for a recipe. Cutting them in half and prying out the seeds with a paring knife makes me yearn for stringing beans. Any suggestions on how to get through this process faster?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just need the pulp (for pie, ice cream, jam, etc...) then cook them down and run them through a food strainer.

If you need them raw, or halved/skins on, then find a good audiobook...

Answer (score 8):

Put the grapes on a plate - best if you do as many at one time as will fill the plate in one layer.  Cover the plate with an identical plate turned upside down. Using a long knife cut between the plates to cut all the grapes in half at once.  I use my thumb nail to scoop out the seeds, but the tip of a vegetable peeler will work better than a knife if your nails aren't long.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this might be a good time to invest in a cherry pitter, as I'd assume it'd work on grapes, too.

Some things to try for speed :

- crushing them, and seeing if the pots pop free (it works for olives).
- cut more than one at a time -- put four or five down on your work surface, place your hand over them, fingers up, and slice between your hand and counter with a sharp knife.  (although, I've never done this for something with pits, so I don't know how much of a problem it might be)

And, when all else fails, buy some seedless grapes, and save the seeded ones for snacking.

**update** : I've since learned a safer method for option #2 : use lids from deli containers or other small items with raised lips (like the bottom of some earthenware plates).  Place it lip-side up, fill with items to be cut in half, place a similar item on top, press down on the stack, and slice in between the two containment devices.

Comment: My cherry pitter is too big for many grapes. But pitters come in different sizes...so look for a small one if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

It's easiest with larger grapes, cut through the middle rather than lengthwise.  The seeds tend to end up in one half and are easily removed with the tip of a paring knife.  I find that the loss of the edible portion of the grape is minimized.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you do it:

1. Cut Grape in half lengthwise, either all the way through or just through to the last skin
2. Remove the seeds from each half with a serrated grapefruit spoon.

Note:  Assembly line is most efficient - pull enough grapes off stem to fill a plate, cut all the grapes in half, then remove the seeds from each grape.

Answer (score 0):

Squeeze grape to seperate pulp from skin and seperate. Bring pulp to boil. At some point pulp will release the seed. Then filter to seperate seed from pulp. Combine unseeded pulp and skins. Ready for pie etc. See Joy of Cooking ..old version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pushing a straw through them? Maybe a stainless straw would work. I may take a Dremel tool to it, to put an edge on the straw!

Answer (score -1):

Just cook them down at a low heat in a saucepan. Allow to cool and squeeze them open then place into a bag and mash with a potato masher lightly.

Seeds will separate from the pulp, which will cook down into a thick juice, strain seeds in a colander/strainer

Comment: Hi, Alicia, welcome to Seasoned Advice! This question already has an accepted answer that you're repeating without adding anything new. This will absolutely not help you build reputation in SE. Perhaps try answering one of our [unanswered questions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/unanswered)

Answer (score -2):

As Fern said,  Squeeze grape and put pulp with seed in a pot.  Put Skin in another bowl.

Heat up the pulp, once heated seed will easily separate from the pulp.   Put through a strainer and add seedless pulp to the skins.

Proceed with recipe

Comment: Given that that was already posted as an answer, what was the point of repeating it?